# Segue from selected collection view cell sends to wrong collection view

Tags: swift, segue, viewcontroller, collectionview

I am using swift. I'm trying to create a collectionView segue to lead to a new viewController.

I have a series of (lets say 8) different images and labels as an array within the collectionView, and the when selected, I want the user to be sent to another view controller (with 8 different possibilities - one for each cell). I have been able to get the app to build, but the behaviour from selecting a cell is wrong.

The first cell that is selected has no response, then the next cell initiates a segue - but to the previously selected one! Each time a different cell is selected, it segues to the previous selected cell. Can anyone help me correct this error?

I have used performSegue and pushViewController separately, following different tutorials on youtube, but each resolves to the same issue.

The various view controllers to segue to have been allocated their own storyboardID in the main.storyboard file. The initial view controller is embedded within a navigation controller, and each new veiwcontroller (to segue to) has been connected to the collection view of the main view controller.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var CollectionView: UICollectionView!

    // created an array for labels

    let NamesForSectionTitles = ["Overview","Canopy trees","Mid-story trees","Understory plants","Birds","Mammals","Ferns","Butterflys"]

    // created list of images to be loaded in the collectionview

    let sectionIconImages: [UIImage] = [
    UIImage(named: "IMG_8750_landscape_night")!,
    UIImage(named: "IMG_8789_Trees")!,
    UIImage(named: "IMG_2185_Tree_Olearia")!,
    UIImage(named: "_MG_9528_Herb_Flower")!,
    UIImage(named: "IMG_3654-")!,
    UIImage(named: "IMG_9892-2")!,
    UIImage(named: "IMG_9496_Ferns_crozier")!,
    UIImage(named: "IMG_7707_Butterfly")!,

    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

// load the data sources and delegate

        CollectionView.dataSource = self
        CollectionView.delegate = self

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return NamesForSectionTitles.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->

        UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell 

            cell.SectionTitle.text = NamesForSectionTitles[indexPath.row]
            cell.sectionImages.image = sectionIconImages[indexPath.row]

            return cell

    }

    // tells the collection view that upon selecting a cell, show the next UIView controller, as suggested in storyboard name (main.storyboard property) - tutoral from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pwZCksvXGRw&list=PLPUDRZDcNNsMdyfZVw4CJDT1Wu8cYx_6E&index=7&t=0s

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: NamesForSectionTitles[indexPath.row], sender: self)

    }
}
```

The viewer should see an image view with a label, that when selected takes them to a new collection view.

Answer (score 0):

Can't Comment so posting an answer

I think
`func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)` is causing the issue.

Please try changing that line to:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Comment: Wow! thanks very much PGDev. I didn't notice that. This fixes my problem entirely.